# How to 301 redirect ALL non-existing page to main domain?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have googled but most uses are when person knows their URLs yet **i want to redirect all possible URLs that give 404/503 errors with 301 to main domain**.

Preferably htaccess since site is html.

So any request to page domain.com/XXXX that doesnt exist should redirect to main instead of giving errors ie:

Not Found

The requested URL /eafsdg was not found on this server.

Answer (score 2):

To redirect all non existent and 503 requests to newdomain, you can use

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://newdomain.com/
ErrorDocument 503 http://newdomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

In NGINX it would be like this :

NOTE: Since I use and I think a lot of people use NGINX as a proxy server, this won't redirect bad pages if the location is a proxy, that needs to be configured on the actual server, so I ended up using starkeen's answer on the end Apache server, but thought id share for NGINX.

```
error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
```

or

```
error_page 404 /;
        location = / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-to-use-custom-error-pages-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.htaccess` code to redirect all `404` page to homepage:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: mind you, if some part of a page is missing, like an image, this will not redirect the whole page, but try to load the root index where the image would be loaded. Same goes for javascript and the like, this could cause some weirdness.

Comment: its mostly not aobut not existign iamges but rather pages ie: domain/sdgdsg or domain/sfsf.html